# Get information about the current dataproc cluster created after workflow submission

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

Suppose I run a pyspark job using a dataproc workflow template and an ephemeral cluster... How can I get the name of the cluster created inside my pyspark job

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to fork out and run this command:

```
/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-cluster-name
```

The only output will be the cluster name, without any new line characters or anything else to cleanup. See [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)